# Javascript working with complex arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

- I have one array of objects, My customerOrder array. Each Object in the array contains a customerID. multiple orders could have the same customerID.
- I also have a second array of objects, my customer array.
- My Goal is to take each object from the customerOrder array and sort them into smaller arrays grouped by the customerID so that I can make each of those individual smaller arrays the value in a key/value pair in my customer array.

Here is what one object in each of the two arrays looks like.

```
      customerOrderArray = ( {
          orderID: '',
          orderType: '',
          customerID: ''
     })

     customerArray = ( {
          ID: '',
          customerName: '',
          customerCity: ''
     })
```

Here is my code that I have tried. That results in only one orderObject being attached to the last customerObject that it iterates through.

```
     for (var k = 0; k < customerOrderArray.length; k++) {
            for (j = 0; j < customerArray.length; j++) {

            allJobs = new Array();

                if (customerArray[j].ID == customerOrderArray[k].CustomerID) {

                   if("allJobs" in customerArray[j]) {
                        customerArray[j].allJobs.push(customerOrderArray[k]);
                    }

                    else {

                        customerArray[j].allJobs.push(customerOrderArray[k]);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

If there is anything I can expand on the help clarify the problem or if an explanation on the broader picture may help let me know. I may be approaching this problem all wrong. I appreciate any help that I can get. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Lodash and its groupBy method https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

Comment: I suppose, providing some example data input and output, would help.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand correctly, you want the result to be an object with the customerID being a key and the value being an object holding name, city and allJobs that belongs to this key.

```
var orderLength = customerOrderArray.length,
    customLength = customerArray.length,
    customerObject = {};

for (var i = 0; i < customLength; i++) { // iterate over customerArray
    var cAi = customerArray[i],
        id = cAi.ID,
        // create an value-object with name, city and an empty allJobs-array
        val = {name: cAi.customerName, city: cAi.customerCity, allJobs: []};

    // iterate over customerOrderArray to find all orders belonging to this id
    for (var o, j = 0; j < orderLength; j++) {
        o = customerOrderArray[j]; 
        // if id is the same push this job into allJobs
        if (o.customerID == id) val.allJobs.push(o);
    }
    // insert this customer into customerObject, key is id and value is val
    customerObject[id] = val;
}
```

So if you have a customer with id 'user25' and say two jobs, a look for `customerObject['user25']` gives:

```
{
    name: 'Ben',
    city: 'New York',
    allJobs: [
        {orderId: 123, orderType: 'mail', customerID: 'user25'},
        {orderId: 124, orderType: 'phone', customerID: 'user25'}
    ]
}
```

The original arrays are not changed. If the customerOrderArray may be emptied during runtime this can be done a bit faster.

If I have misunderstood something or this doesn't fit otherwise please post critique.